# Audio Visualizer for WebRTC

Tags: html, audio, webrtc

I am trying to use www.rtcmulticonnection.org, spefically: http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/onstream/

I want to be able to grab the video element and connect it to a frequency analyzer.

I have tried $("video").get(0).connect

But that is not even a function, attempting on chrome. I do have an `audiocontext`, and a `webrtc` connection working. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would like to help, but gonna need bit more details, the question is kinda vague...

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [this example](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/volume/) which queries a local stream volume using the WebAudio API?

In Chrome this has only been recently (M49 or M50) been fixed to work with remote streams received via a RTCPeerConnection.

Note that you will need the MediaStream object typically, not the video element.

Comment: That uses the local mic; however, I am going to look into if that works with non-local mic. Thank you for the resource.